# Youtube Data API error: Subtitles are disabled for this video

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im trying to get the Title and transcript of all videos of a playlist:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
import os

api_key = "*********************************"

#1.query API 
rq = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey=api_key).playlistItems().list(
        part="contentDetails, snippet",
        playlistId="PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p",
        maxResults=50,        
        ).execute()
        
#2.Create a list with video Ids and Titles
vid_ids = []
vid_title = []
for item in rq["items"]:
    vid_ids.append(item["contentDetails"]["videoId"])
    vid_title.append(item["snippet"]["title"])

#3.Get transcripts
srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts(vid_ids)
print(srt)
```

But I get an error because one or more of those videos have no subtitles:

```
Could not retrieve a transcript for the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2lwk1Ukgz0! This is most likely caused by:

Subtitles are disabled for this video
```

What would you code in python to avoid this error, and get the transcripts of at least the rest of the videos of the playlist? maybe an If Statement (if the video has no subtitles jump to the next one) or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and except should help here:

```py
for id in vid_ids:
    try:
        srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts(id)
    except:
        print(f"{id} doesn't have a transcript")
```

This will basically ignore exceptions and tell you which id doesn't have a transcript.

Answer (score 1):

Just try one video id at a time to get its transcript using `try`/`except` and pay attention not to pass directly a video id but instead an array of one video id to `YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts` otherwise it doesn't work.

So change:

```
#3.Get transcripts
srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts(vid_ids)
print(srt)
```

For:

```
#3.Get transcripts
srt = []
for vid_id in vid_ids:
    try:
        srt += [YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcripts([vid_id])]
    except:
        srt += [({vid_id => []}, [])]
print(srt)
```